# Using the Intermediate Value Theorem to show points on a graph

Tags: calculus, continuity

$Let$ $f(x)=$ $\frac{2x^2-x-1}{x-2}$

$d)$ Use the Intermediate Value Theorem to show that there exist at least two points $x$ $\in$ $\mathbb R$ for which $f(x)=-\pi$. (Hint: Sketch the graph.)

[image: This is the graph drawn out]

So here I've graphed the equation in question and I can clearly see that $f(x)=-\pi$ has two solutions. The problem I'm having is using the IVT to actually show this.

I know that if $y_0$ is any value between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ on an open interval $[a,b]$ then there exists a $c$ in $[a,b]$ such that $y_0=f(c)$ but I don't understand how I can apply this to this particular equiation as I'm trying to find two points.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Okay so while writing this I've realised that I could take any value of $y$ that is less then $-\pi$, for example $f(-10)$, and then take something greater than $-\pi$ where the graph is still continuous, say $f(0)$, and show that there is a sign change between the two values.

i.e $f(-10)=-\frac{209}{12}$ and $f(0)=\frac{1}{2}$ so $f(x)=-\pi$ lies between the two solutions

I'm not even sure if this is right, but does this work as an answer?

Comment: What do you mean by $x = \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Whoops, good spot. I meant to say $x$  $\epsilon$ $\mathbb R$

Comment: About your edit, this is the right way to do it. But so far, you've only shown that one solution exists (the one between $-10$ and $0$). You can do the same thing to show the existence of the other solution

Comment: @Farnight , I don't actually know how my edit shows that I've located one solution in the first place. Just saying there is a sign change between $-10$ and $0$ implies a solution is $-\pi$ is surely far too ambiguous.

Comment: If the function is continuous on that domain, then all we need is a sign change.

Comment: btw, I meant a sign change of $f(x)+\pi$, not $f(x)$

Comment: Ah thank you very much @Farnight I've cracked the problem now. Seems as though it was just a case of the wording being a bit difficult after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is continuous on $(-\infty, 2)$ with $f(-\infty) \to -\infty$ and $f(2-) \to -\infty$ and maximum value of $7 - 2\sqrt(10) > -\pi$, so it must cross $y=-\pi$ line at least twice.